# websocket fails on iPad, iPhone when server is on google cloud

Tags: iphone, tomcat, ipad, websocket, cloud

I have a Spring Boot application running on Google cloud container engine.
I have created containers, service and load balancer using kubernetes templates. The load balancer is ingress resource.

When I try to connect to the app using webscoket it does not work on iPad, iPhone.

It works in local environment, when iPad and the Spring Boot server is in the same network.
It works when connecting from Chrome running on PC.

The only combination that fails is from iPad, iPhone to Google Cloud.
I do not have the SSL setup.

Is there any reason why this should not work?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution. I have replaced the Tomcat with Undertow server in the Spring Boot and it started working correctly.

Basically the issue is that following setup does not work:

WebSocket on iOS --> Google cloud load balancer --> Spring Boot on Tomcat

Maybe I am missing some configuration to make tomcat work.